# Installing rear fog lights

Tags: nissan, murano, rear, fog

I have a Nissan Murano 2009 LE (made in Japan for California) which came with OEM front fog lights. It doesn't have rear fog lights.

Now I want to install the rear fog light(s). I couldn't find anything in the service manual about the rear fog lights so there is no built-in harness/support for that. This means that the lights must installed from scratch.

Now, I have read the service manual, I've checked the wiring diagram for the front fog lights so basically the things look like this:
- the combination switch sends the signal to the BCM which in turn sends a request signal to the IPDM which finally turns the integrated front fog lamp relay ON/OFF.

The 15A front fog lamp fuse has number #58 and is located on the IPDM
on engine compartment. The IPDM has a large E345 connector which has
multiple terminals. The terminals #86 and #87 are the one that
supplies the 12V for the right and respectively the left front fog lights.

So to install the rear fog lights would theoretically mean to install a wire from that E345 IPDM connector (terminal #86 and/or #87 ) to the rear of the body and there to connect that new wire to the rear fog lamps. Obviously the ground is taken from the car's chassis. Now, I intend to install a [LED fog lamp](http://www.ebay.com/itm/252335403159?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2648&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) (at least one on the left/driver side) which uses like 3.8W (ie. about 0.3A=3.8W/12V).

The required wire length would be ~7m. The maximum Amps for an AWG18 insulated wire (ie. chassis wiring) is 16A so I think that it would be safe to use a 16A wire on a 0.3A circuit. To make sure the circuit is safe I would install a 15A fuse (by using a [mini fuse holder](http://www.ebay.com/itm/201397865763?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)). The wire would be inserted through a flexible cable conduit starting from the engine compartment (from the IPDM which is right in front of the driver) then following the body interior line like the all other OEM harness.

Is there anything I should be concerned of before starting to make this happen? Any hint from a car electrician?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good plan, if you are fitting both left and right hand then you should run two wires.

Have you checked the wiring at the lamps to check to see if the wires already exist - many manufacturers have one loom with all the wires for most things included as it is cheaper that making 15 versions...

If using the ecu proves difficult, then you could use a relay and switch using the sidelight circuit for the switched supply (control) and a fused feed from the battery.

Comment: Thanks for the two wires hint. I haven't check the front fog lamps wiring, so I don't know if they already considered such a wire. A good tips, though. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I installed my rear fog lights. I have documented all the steps I've made on my blog so hopefully it would help others like me.
Here is the link: http://mynixworld.info/2017/05/10/installing-rear-fog-light-nissan-murano